# how to properly execute a `SET` query in java using jdbc driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am able to make a connection to my database but unable to execute a `SET` query properly. From looking at the documentation, I should be using `execute` not `executeQuery` or `executeUpdate`. I have a working `connection` and this is the rest :

```java
 try (Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
        boolean result = st.execute("SET search_path TO '712275-8S8DH-74DASS'");
        ResultSet queryResult = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(customer.last_updated) from customer");
        while (queryResult.next()) {
          String lastUpdated = queryResult.getString("last_updated");
        }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
 }
```

I get these exceptions: `The column name last_updated was not found in this ResultSet.` and `No data from query` which makes me think the search_path hasn't been set properly because when I make a direct connection using `psql`, I am able to get results by running

```sql
postgres=> SET search_path TO '712275-8S8DH-74DASS';
SET
postgres=> SELECT MAX(customer.last_updated) from customer;
[expected result]
```

Comment: I somehow think the `[expected result]` does not show the column name as `last_updated`

Comment: You should be using `getObject(..., LocalDateTime.class)` to begin with - don't retrieve timestamps as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't return the result in a column called `last_updated`.
That's because you are doing an aggregate operation.
I think the column returned by the query is called `max`.

This might work:

```
String lastUpdated = queryResult.getString("max");
```

Or you can use an alias:

```
ResultSet queryResult = st.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(customer.last_updated) as last_updated from customer");
```

Comment: or `queryResult.getString(1);`